# Search every column, of every database of every schema for a regular expression

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I'm working for a company undergoing acquisition at the moment. They use Oracle 11g and have a requirement for identifying all references to the current company name in their databases and having these listed by the schema/owner, table, column and number of occurrences in that column.

I've used the following with some success, as taken from another answer.

```
     SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 100000
DECLARE
  match_count INTEGER;
BEGIN
  FOR T IN
  (
    SELECT owner, table_name, column_name
    FROM all_tab_columns
    WHERE
   OWNER <> 'SYS' AND DATA_TYPE LIKE '%CHAR%'
  ) LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
      'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || t.owner || '.' || t.table_name ||
      ' WHERE '||t.column_name||' = :1'
      INTO MATCH_COUNT
      USING 'NAME';

    IF MATCH_COUNT > 0 THEN
      dbms_output.put_line( t.owner ||' '|| t.table_name ||' '||t.column_name||' '||match_count );
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

However it only finds literal strings of NAME and I also want to find Name, Name Shops, Name Accounts, Name someOtherStringICantGuess etc. So I think i should use a regular expression. I'm fine with the regular expression part, but it's how to incorporate it into the above functionality I'm unsure of. In fact i'm uncertain whether I will be adapting the above code, or doing something completely different.

One last thing: performance and duration of the run of the script are irrelevant and subordinate to the certainty of every column being checked. There is a dedicated environment that mimics production where this script will be deployed so it won't adversely affect the company's customers.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Just removed some company specific code...

Comment: See [**SQL to Search for a VALUE in all COLUMNS of all TABLES in an entire SCHEMA**](https://lalitkumarb.com/2015/01/06/sql-to-search-for-a-value-in-all-columns-of-all-atbles-in-an-entire-schema/)

Comment: Please look at [REGEXP_LIKE documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm). You will also need to use the third parameter (`match_parameter`) set to `'i'` which specifies case-insensitive matching.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. This is going to seem needlessly picky, but is there a way to do this with an anonymous block instead of creating a procedure? I don't know how to do this and am not even sure I should in this database.
Also I know how to use REGEXP_LIKE. It's integrating this into dynamic PLSQL, either that detailed above or another, completely different example that is the problem.

Comment: Well, I really don't see what's the issue. Just use `' WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('||t.column_name||', :1, ''i'')'` instead of `' WHERE '||t.column_name||' = :1'`, and that should do. `:1` should be a regular expression.

Comment: As for your concern, I don't understand it — you already have an anonymous block. And working with data dictionary is a task that is fine to do in DB.

Comment: Sorry That young man, I was referring to the first answer. I should have specified. They suggested creating a procedure.

I've tried that, but am getting the following error:-

ERROR at line 13:
ORA-06550: line 13, column 38:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'
ORA-06550: line 13, column 17:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to surround your search with `upper`.

```
    SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 100000

DECLARE
   -- set l_wildcard_search to true if you are using wildcards ('%'),
   -- false if you want a straight match on the name
   -- Wild card searches (like) are not able to use indexes whereas '='
   -- potentially can.
   l_wildcard_search   CONSTANT BOOLEAN := FALSE;
   match_count                  INTEGER;
   --
   l_searchvalue                VARCHAR2 (100) := UPPER ('NAME');
   l_cmd                        VARCHAR2 (200);
BEGIN
   FOR t IN (SELECT owner, table_name, column_name
               FROM all_tab_columns
              WHERE owner NOT IN ('SYS', 'SYSTEM')
                AND data_type LIKE '%CHAR%')
   LOOP
      BEGIN
         l_cmd      :=    'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '
                       || t.owner
                       || '.'
                       || t.table_name
                       || ' WHERE upper('
                       || t.column_name
                       || ')'
                       || CASE WHEN l_wildcard_search THEN ' like ' ELSE ' = ' END
                       || ':1';
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_cmd);

         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_cmd INTO match_count USING l_searchvalue;

         IF match_count > 0
         THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (t.owner || ' ' || t.table_name || ' ' || t.column_name || ' ' || match_count);
         END IF;
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS
         THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Error executing: ' || l_cmd);
      END;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. That will be useful for finding values like Name, but it won't allow me to find values like 'Name Owner' etc. I'll incorporate it and continue dealing with the other possibilities. Cheers!

Comment: Well, for that you just need `LIKE` with wildcards (`%`) on both sides.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use like as it's too 'liberal'. It finds things like NAME_CONVENTION, ENAMEL, RENAME, FIRST_NAME etc. The Regular expression is ready and has been tested on every conceivable variation in that excludes irrelevancies and lists the required values. It just needs plugged in if I can get the rest to work.

Comment: I updated the code so that it will use equality or like. You can easily substitute in the regular expression into l_cmd if that is your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer using regular expressions

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 100000

DECLARE

   match_count                  INTEGER;
   l_searchvalue                VARCHAR2 (100) := UPPER ('NAME');
   l_cmd                        VARCHAR2 (200);
BEGIN
   FOR t IN (SELECT owner, table_name, column_name
               FROM all_tab_columns
              WHERE owner NOT IN ('SYS', 'SYSTEM')
                AND data_type LIKE '%CHAR%' and rownum < 10)
   LOOP
      BEGIN
         l_cmd      :=    'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '
                       || t.owner
                       || '.'
                       || t.table_name
                       || ' WHERE regexp_like('
                       || t.column_name
                       || ', :1)';
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_cmd);

         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_cmd INTO match_count USING l_searchvalue;

         IF match_count > 0
         THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (t.owner || ' ' || t.table_name || ' ' || t.column_name || ' ' || match_count);
         END IF;
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS
         THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Error executing: ' || l_cmd);
      END;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```